# Jquery ZeroClipboard not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, zeroclipboard

I am trying to implement zero clipboard on my web mobile application but I can't make it work. Can you help me checking what I am doing wrong? Cheers!

HTML code:

```
<div class="p_btns" style="">
<input type="hidden" id="copy_field" value="cool">
<div id="btn_copy" class="p_btns_link" >Copy my referral link</div>
```

JS ZCLIP

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#btn_copy").zclip({
    path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',

    copy:$("input#copy_field").val(),

    beforeCopy:function(){
        $( "#btn_copy" ).animate({
          backgroundColor: "#70c280",
          color: "#fff",

        }, 100 );
    },

    afterCopy:function(){
         $( "#btn_copy" ).animate({
          backgroundColor: "#4e798f",
          color: "#fff",

        }, 500 );

        alert('copied');
    }
});
```

Comment: do you see any errors in the console ? Are you sure `ZeroClipboard.swf` is in the right location?

Comment: Thanks @DhirajBodicherla. Simply doesn't work I got no errors.

Comment: yes ZeroClipboard.swf is in the JS folder with the zclip.js

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there zClip does not work on iOS =/